# Android NDK get mobile network info

Tags: android, networking, android-ndk, android-networking, telephony

I have C++ code which can take a network info(struct ifaddrs) via netlink.

But I can't obtain next field:

- network type - WIFI or MOBILE
- mobile network type - like NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA, NETWORK_TYPE_LTE etc..

Any idea how can I get this info without Java(only C/C++) ?

How can I get info about mobile internet connection and assign it with network?